# KACE setlang.vbs error compile

Tags: vbscript

Please help, I am unable to execute it from cmd, & through an error as " C:\setlang.vbs(4, 32) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected end of stat
ement.

please can you find what the error in this below code.

```
Dim argCount : argCount = Wscript.Arguments.Count
If (argCount < 2) Then
    Wscript.Echo "setlang.vbs - Modify the package language field of an MSI installer file" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "usage: cscript setlang.vbs <msi_file_path> <lcid>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "example: cscript setlang.vbs C:\temp\ampagent-5.4.1000-x86.msi 1033" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Copyright (C) 2012 Dell Inc.  All rights reserved."
    Wscript.Quit 1
End If

Dim dbPath : dbPath = Wscript.Arguments(0)
Dim lcid : lcid = Wscript.Arguments(1)

On Error Resume Next
Dim installer : Set installer = Nothing
Set installer = Wscript.CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer") : CheckError
Dim database : Set database = installer.OpenDatabase(dbPath, 1) : CheckError
Dim sumInfo : Set sumInfo = database.SummaryInformation(1) : CheckError
Dim template : template = sumInfo.Property(7) : CheckError
Dim iDelim : iDelim = InStr(1, template, ";", vbTextCompare)
Dim platform : If iDelim = 0 Then platform = ";" Else platform = Left(template, iDelim)
sumInfo.Property(7) = platform & lcid
sumInfo.Persist : CheckError
database.Commit : CheckError
Set database = nothing
Wscript.Echo "Successfully set package language = " & lcid
Wscript.Quit 0

Sub CheckError
    Dim msg, errRec
    If Err = 0 Then Exit Sub
    msg = Err.Source & " " & Hex(Err) & ": " & Err.Description
    If Not installer Is Nothing Then
        Set errRec = installer.LastErrorRecord
        If Not errRec Is Nothing Then msg = msg & vbNewLine & errRec.FormatText
    End If
    Wscript.Echo msg
    Wscript.Quit 2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no error here.

If your spacing is the same in your file as your post then you have a CR before the dot in setlang.vbs on line 4.

If using notepad to write it copy and paste into wordpad to check line breaks. Notepad totally ignores and hides carriage returns but other programs don't. Notepad only looks for line feeds. If coping from browser based documentation such as web pages and help systems sometimes stray carriage returns get invisibly inserted in notepad.